a) given $a>0$ and given the curve described by the equation: $(x^2+y^2-ax)^2=a^2(x^2+y^2)$; b) find the length of the curve
I am given a hint

hint: use polar coordinates, $(x(t),y(t))=(r(t)\cos t,r(t)\sin t)$ and find $r(t)$

1.- I did this and using bhaskara got that $r(t)=-acost±a$.
But now I dont know how to continue, should i use  $r(t)=-a\cos t+a$ or $r(t)=-a\cos t-a$?
2.- And then, should i plug it in the equation to calculate the integral and find the length of the curve?

Welcome to MSE. I took the liberty of using latex to edit your post, so that your post complies with the rules of MSE. I invite you via the EDIT command to see how I proceeded for the future.

What do you mean by "using bhaskara" ? I used an equation in $r$ of degree $2$ to find $r$

I think there are some points you need to clarify. First of all, computing the solutions of the equation of degree 2 in $r$ I get that $r(t) = a cos(t)\pm a$. At this point, I would also ask myself for what values of $t$ the radius is positive.

$L=\int_a^b \sqrt{r'(\theta)^2 + r(\theta)^2} ;\mathrm d\theta$

The cardioid $(x^2+y^2-ax)^2=a^2(x^2+y^2)$ has the rational parametrization $(x,y)=(2a\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2},2a\frac{2t}{(1+t^2)^2}).$ Using this (usually called the $\tan{\frac{\theta}2}$ trick) we can evaluate the length integral. $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{(2a\frac{2 t (t^2 - 3)}{(1 + t^2)^3})^2+(2a\frac{-(2 (3 t^2 - 1))}{(1+t^2)^3)})^2}dt=\2 a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{((2 - 6 t^2)^2 + (2 t (t^2 - 3))^2)/(t^2 + 1)^6}dt=\4a \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{(t^2 + 1)^\frac32}=8a.$$

1.- I don't know what "using bhaskara" means, but you've almost got it. Here is what I did :
$\begin{cases}x(t)=r(t) \cos t\\y(t)=r(t)\sin t , \text{ with }r(t)\geq0 \end{cases}$
To simplify in the following implications, I will note $r$ instead of $r(t)$ for a fixed $t\in \mathbb R$.
$(r^2-ar \cos t)^2=a^2r^2\implies r^2[(r-a\cos t)^2-a^2]=0$ $$\implies \begin{cases} r=0\\ \lor \\ r-a\cos t-a=0 \\ \lor \\r-a\cos t +a=0 \end{cases}$$ $$ \implies\begin {cases} 
r= 0\\ \lor \\ r=a\cos t+a \\ \lor \\ r=a\cos t-a \end{cases}\\$$
We have to exclude $r=a(\cos t-1)$as @rcescon pointed out to you.
2.- You can find the answer here using $$L=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{r'(\theta)^2 + r(\theta)^2} \;\mathrm d\theta$$

You can see the curves here.
